# OpenCV Android, drawing largest contour, something is wrong

Tags: java, android, opencv, contour, canny-operator

I am trying to draw a largest contour, I am working in realtime, processing each camera frame. 
My input image is going to be hand, I have a few constraints - black background, no specular light.

I expect largest contour to be as close as possible to below image[image]

My code is as below, I have referred many samples available online, and I am almost at a thought that there is nothing wrong in my code.

```
        mRgba = inputFrame.gray();
        contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        mcontours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        List<Mat> hull = new ArrayList<Mat>(contours.size());

        hierarchy = new Mat();
        Imgproc.Canny(inputFrame.gray(), mIntermediateMat, 50, 50);
        Imgproc.findContours(mIntermediateMat, contours, hierarchy,
                Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);


        for (int idx = 0; idx != contours.size(); ++idx)
        {
            Mat contour = contours.get(idx);
            double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
            Log.i(TAG, "maxAreaIdx =" + idx + "contourarea = " + contourarea);
            if (contourarea > maxArea)
            {
                maxArea = contourarea;
                maxAreaIdx = idx;
                Log.i(TAG, "maxAreaIdx =" + maxAreaIdx + "MaxArea = " + maxArea);

            }

        }

        if(maxAreaIdx > 0 && maxAreaIdx < contours.size())
            mcontours.add(contours.get(maxAreaIdx));
        else
            break;

        Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA,
                4);
        hierarchy.release();
        Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, mcontours, -1, CONTOUR_COLOR, -1);
```

Now, all I get is a very small fraction of this. My current understanding is that OpenCV itself is not able detect big continuous contour. Please refer to images below.

[image]

Not only this, I tested it for other images as well, but I am somehow not able to get large big continuous contour.

Am I wrong in applying Canny first? Is there a better technique? I wish to get outline of the hand contour. In future, I want to compare it with saved similar database of contours. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score -1):

Try this one :

```
List<MatOfPoint> mContours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

//"tes" is binary image from threshold result       
Imgproc.findContours(tes, mContours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, new Point(0,0));
    Mat overlay = contImg; //this is source image RGB
    for(int i = 0; i < mContours.size(); i++)
    {
            Imgproc.drawContours(overlay, mContours, -1, red, 2); //draw contour
    }
    return overlay;
```

Hope it will help you